# Ruby parslet: parsing multiple lines

Tags: ruby, lines, parslet

I'm looking for a way to match multiple lines Parslet.
The code looks like this:

```
rule(:line) { (match('$').absent? >> any).repeat >> match('$') }
rule(:lines) { line.repeat }
```

However, `lines` will always end up in an infinite loop which is because `match('$')` will endlessly repeat to match end of string.

**Is it possible to match multiple lines that can be empty?**

```
irb(main)> lines.parse($stdin.read)
This
is

a
multiline

string^D
```

should match successfully. Am I missing something? I also tried `(match('$').absent? >> any.maybe).repeat(1) >> match('$')` but that doesn't match empty lines.

Regards,
Danyel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two, related, problems with your matching:

- The pseudo-character match `$` does not consume any real characters. You still need to consume the newlines somehow.
- Parslet is munging the input in some way, making `$` match in places you might not expect. The best result I could get using `$` ended up matching each individual character.

Much safer to use `\n` as the end-of-line character. I got the following to work (I am somewhat of a beginner with Parslet myself, so apologies if it could be clearer):

```
require 'parslet'

class Lines < Parslet::Parser
    rule(:text) { match("[^\n]") }
    rule(:line) { ( text.repeat(0) >> match("\n") ) | text.repeat(1) }
    rule(:lines) { line.as(:line).repeat }
    root :lines
end

s = "This
is

a
multiline
string"

p Lines.new.parse( s )
```

The rule for the line is complex because of the need to match empty lines and a possible final line without a `\n`.

You don't have to use the `.as(:line)` syntax - I just added it to show clearly that the `:line` rule is matching each line individually, and not simply consuming the whole input.

Comment: This looks like a nice solution. My workaround was to work with `\n`, too and to add a newline to the incoming string in order to prevent match failure at the end. This looks cleaner, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I usually define a rule for end_of_line. This is based on the trick in http://kschiess.github.io/parslet/tricks.html for matching end_of_file.

```
class MyParser < Parslet::Parser
  rule(:cr)         { str("\n") }
  rule(:eol?)       { any.absent? | cr }
  rule(:line_body)  { (eol?.absent? >> any).repeat(1) }
  rule(:line)       { cr | line_body >> eol? }
  rule(:lines?)     { line.repeat (0)}
  root(:lines?)
end

puts MyParser.new.parse(""" this is a line
so is this

that was too
This ends""").inspect
```

Obviously if you want to do more with the parser than you can achieve with String::split("\n") you will replace the `line_body` with something useful :)

---

I had a quick go at answering this question and mucked it up. I just though I would explain the mistake I made, and show you how to avoid mistakes of that kind.

Here is my first answer.

```
rule(:eol)   { str('\n') | any.absent?  }
rule(:line)  { (eol.absent? >> any).repeat >> eol }
rule(:lines) { line.as(:line).repeat }
```

I didn't follow my usual rules:

- Always make repeat count explicit
- Any rule that can match zero length strings, should have name ending in a '?'

So lets apply these...

```
rule(:eol?)   { str('\n') | any.absent?  } 
# as the second option consumes nothing

rule(:line?)  { (eol.absent? >> any).repeat(0) >> eol? } 
# repeat(0) can consume nothing

rule(:lines?) { line.as(:line?).repeat(0) }
# We have a problem! We have a rule that can consume nothing inside a `repeat`!
```

Here see why we get an infinite loop. As the input is consumed, you end up with just the `end of file`, which matches `eol?` and hence `line?` (as the line body can be empty). Being inside `lines`' `repeat`, it keeps matching without consuming anything and loops forever.

We need to change the line rule so it always consumes something.

```
rule(:cr)         { str('\n') }
rule(:eol?)       { cr | any.absent?  }
rule(:line_body)  { (eol.absent? >> any).repeat(1) }
rule(:line)       { cr | line_body >> eol? }
rule(:lines?)     { line.as(:line).repeat(0) }
```

Now `line` has to match something, either a `cr` (for empty lines), or at least one character followed by the optional `eol?`. All `repeat`s have bodies that consume something. We are now golden.

Comment: This turns into an infinite loop for me.

Comment: oops. yes I'll fix that.

Comment: Infinite loops happen when you have rules that can match without consuming any input. Here `line` matches an empty line, followed by the `any.absent?` version of `eol` which also doesn't consume anything, so it can keep matching.